# Why is this undefined when I call a functions property?

Tags: javascript, function, object, properties

Here is my code:

```js
function myOuterFunction() {

    myInnerFunction();

    var myObject = {say: myInnerFunction.myProperty1,
                  say2: myInnerFunction.myProperty2
                };


    function myInnerFunction(){

      return {myProperty1: "hello",
              myProperty2: "world"
             };
    }
    

console.log(myObject);
}
myOuterFunction();
```

Why I am not able to geht the functions property?

I know I could solve this with another variable but why isnt this solution possible?

Thanks

Comment: Call the function...

Comment: Calling `myInnerFunction()` doesn't magically apply the return value to the function itself. You need to assign the return value to something (`var properties = myInnerFunction()`) and then access the return value (`properties.myProperty1`).

Comment: `myInnerFunction` refers to the function object itself, not the value it returns when called. You could do `myInnerFunction().myProperty1` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the value of the function before using it.

```js
function myOuterFunction() {
  var data = myInnerFunction();
  var myObject = {
    say: data.myProperty1,
    say2: data.myProperty2
  };
  function myInnerFunction() {
    return {
      myProperty1: "hello",
      myProperty2: "world"
    };
  }
  console.log(myObject);
}
myOuterFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

your mistakes are
1) try not to use myInnerFunction() inside myOuterFunction(). it's not a good programming practice
2) calling  myInnerFunction() does nothing when calling it out in the open. you are not even giving it's return value to a variable.
3) calling  myInnerFunction without () doesn't tell javascript that the it is a function

this is the way you should write it

```
function myOuterFunction() {
    var myObject = {say: myInnerFunction().myProperty1,
                      say2: myInnerFunction().myProperty2
                    };

    console.log(myObject);
}
function myInnerFunction(){

      return {myProperty1: "hello",
              myProperty2: "world"
             };
}
myOuterFunction();
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I always avoid to implement functions in a function?

Comment: javascript doen't have any issues with it but it's a better practice if you don't. because it will become a habit and you will use it in other programming languages and that leads to errors. it's just a recommendation